# Changes in Unity tweak tool is not applying

Tags: unity-tweak-tool

When I am changing the settings of the launcher in unity tweak tool it is not applying, it's just changing in the tool but not appearing on the system.

Comment: Did you give this command `sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool`?

Comment: Are you the owner of all files/directories in your home directory? You could try `sudo chown -R username:username ~` (change username to your own user name). You should be able to do this safely.